# Unable to successfully upload to Google Cloud with a signed url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

Was hoping to get some insight to see what I might be missing since I'm noticing the video I'm trying to upload isn't working.

I first get a signedURL that connects to my bucket successfully. I then

```
  const submitVideo = async () => {
    const url = await getSignedUrl({
      variables: { filename: "google.jpeg" }
    }).then(async response => {
      if (response.data && response.data.getSignedUrl) {
        const url = response.data.getSignedUrl.url;
        const pathUrl = url.split('?');
        const videoPath = pathUrl[0];
        
        const uploadedReponse = await uploadToGoogleCloud(url);
      }
    });
  }

  const uploadToGoogleCloud = async (url) => {
    const videoFile = await fetch(video.uri);
    const blob = await videoFile.blob();
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: blob,
    }).then(res => console.log("thres is ", res)).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

When I worked with AWS. Doing this worked without an issue.

```
    const type = video.split('.').pop();
    const videoFile = await fetch(video);
    const blob = await videoFile.blob();
    const response = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: blob,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': type,
            'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
        }
    }).catch((e) => console.log('THE ERROR FOR VIDEO UPLOAD IS ', e));
```

Is it because I am missing Content-Type and x-amz-acl? I'm not seeing any error appear which is why I was hoping to get some insight. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'isn't working'? Is your video uploaded (size >0) but not readable on your browser?

Comment: What error message and response to the request you made are you getting?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I mean nothing is being successfully uploaded to my Google Cloud project. The blob info that gets returned is `{"_data":{"size":8869426,"offset":0,"blobId":"81077730-EC27-46D9-A847-B22ADEF16966","type":"video/quicktime","name":"A58EE477-63CF-4B53-BB36-60C46F59A918.mov","__collector":{}}}` There is a size of the video present. I'm just not sure why it won't get uploaded plus when I do a `.then` or .`catch` nothing gets returned.

Comment: @RafaelLemos I'm not sure why but my `.then` and `.catch` is returning nothing. I try to do a console.log to see what is returned and nothing is appearing in my terminal.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I solve the problem. I needed to mention the right content-type. IOS Mov is quicktime

Comment: @Yama If you have successfully fixed the issue you were facing please post it as an answer so that others in the community can refer to it if they go through the same, plus you can accept the answer and increase your reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem that I was having. I was submitting in my `getSignedUrl` request with the wrong content-type. Since I am currently using an IOS phone, the videos being retrieved are `.mov`. This within google states it to be 'video/quicktime'.

This type information can be referenced at `https://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/`

Hope this helps anyone who might get stuck in wondering why a video isn't being pushed to their bucket